# Website FB-Comments not showing up right

Tags: html, facebook, comments

I didnt find an answer for me. so maybe you can help me.

I embedded the facebook commentbox in my website and finally the box shows up. but it seems that the  is not high enough to show up well

I tried to put a height-tag into the code, but the problem remains.

Has anybody an idea? The Code is the one I got from the developers page

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="my website url" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

Thats what happens

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

I had to allow the facebook-cookies in my browser.

I'll leave the question, maybe it could be useful for someone else.